# trace xquery variables

Tags: debugging, xquery

i am working with BEA (now called Oracle Service Bus Worskshop) xquery and I am trying to figure out a way to simply debug my code. Something like "echo" in bash or System.out() in Java.
The Workshop IDE (Eclipse) has a built in tool to test the all xquery file, returning the final output.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

you could try the `trace` function (http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-xpath-functions-11-20091215/#func-trace).

For example:

```
for $x in (1 to 3)
return trace($x, "I'm tracing x")
```

should log each value of `$x` somewhere and returns exactly the same result as:

```
for $x in (1 to 3)
return $x
```

Yet, I neither know if this is supported in Oracles implementation nor where it might log the traced values.

Comment: Yes, I knew that function. But as you also mentioned depends on vendor implementatio and since Oracle doesn't say pretty much anything about I sounds like doesn't worth to spend too much time on it. Better to find alternative ways such as external software that also debug. The only problem is any product I am testing return a different behavior; not really sure on how this language is supported across different platform.